# Rewriting FULL URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there anyway to rewrite the full URL, even with parameters via .htdocs using mod-rewrite?

The thing is, for example, if I type www.example.org, it has to forward me to www.example.org/index.php/frontend.

Anyone's got an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the host name, and if it matches `www.example.org`, redirect everything (including the path and any parameters, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.org/index.php/frontend/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you alok for your answer, but it seems that is still not working, even thoug I'll continue trying and post the result if solved.

Comment: There was a problem in the RewriteCond, I removed the ! because the rule should get executed if the host matches with ^www.example.org$